# Retain trailing zeros after multiplication XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, xslt-2.0

I have a problem in which I need to retain the trailing zeros after the mathematical computation.

For eg: 9854.32000 * 1 should return 9854.32000 instead of 9854.32. I tried using

`<xsl:decimal-format name="test" decimal-separator="."/>`

`<xsl:value-of select="format-number(26825.8000 * 1, '#.000', 'test')"/>`

But I would like to learn if there is a way for me to do this generically by counting the length of trailing zeros and append them to the result

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *picture* string of `format-number()` can be calculated. Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <multiplicand>1</multiplicand>
    <multiplicand>2.0</multiplicand>
    <multiplicand>3.14</multiplicand>
    <multiplicand>4.000</multiplicand>
    <multiplicand>5.0000</multiplicand>
    <multiplicand>6.12345</multiplicand>
    <multiplicand>7.000000</multiplicand>
</input>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="multiplier" select="2"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="multiplicand">
            <xsl:variable name="zeros" select="translate(substring-after(., '.'), '123456789', '000000000')" />
            <product>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(. * $multiplier, concat('#.', $zeros))" />
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <product>2</product>
   <product>4.0</product>
   <product>6.28</product>
   <product>8.000</product>
   <product>10.0000</product>
   <product>12.24690</product>
   <product>14.000000</product>
</output>
```